# No puedo abrir un informe de crystal con una base de datos en Microsoft Access con contraseña

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

No consigo abrir un informe de Crystal Reports con contraseña. Me sale una pantalla del informe que me pide la contraseña. Adjunto captura.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna solución?

```
        Dim RptDocument As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument

        RptDocument.Load("c:\Informe.rpt", CrystalDecisions.Shared.OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByDefault)

        RptDocument.DataSourceConnections.Clear()

        Dim CTableLogInfo As CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo
        Dim ConnInfo As CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo = New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo()

        ConnInfo.Type = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfoType.CRQE
        ConnInfo.ServerName = String.Empty
        ConnInfo.DatabaseName = "c:\dbConPasswrod.mdb"
        ConnInfo.UserID = "Admin"
        ConnInfo.Password = "5354"
        ConnInfo.AllowCustomConnection = False
        ConnInfo.IntegratedSecurity = False

        For Each CTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table In RptDocument.Database.Tables
            CTable.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = ConnInfo
            CTableLogInfo = CTable.LogOnInfo
            CTableLogInfo.ReportName = "Informe.rpt"
            CTableLogInfo.TableName = CTable.Name
            CTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(CTableLogInfo)
        Next

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = RptDocument
        CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de cientos de pruebas he dado con la solución.

Adjunto código para quien lo necesite.

Con este código podéis asignar la ubicación de una base de datos, su contraseña al informe deseado.

```
        Dim cr As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
        Dim crCon As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo
        Dim crtableLogoninfos As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfos
        Dim crtableLogoninfo As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo
        Dim CrTables As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Tables
        Dim CrTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table

        cr.Load("c:\Informe.rpt")

        With crCon
            .ServerName = "c:\dbConPasswrod.mdb"
            .UserID = "Admin"
            .Password = Chr(10) & "5354"
        End With

        CrTables = cr.Database.Tables
        For Each CrTable In CrTables
            crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo
            crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crCon
            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo)
        Next

        ' Load Report to cr viewer
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr
        CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta simplemente usando el `SetLogon()`

```
RptDocument.DataSourceConnections.Item(0).SetLogon("admin", "xx")
```

Quita la definicio del `ConnInfo` ya que esta aplica a la conexion a servicio de base de datos.

[Change Crystal Report Connection at Runtime in Visual studio 2005](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14997/Change-Crystal-Report-Connection-at-Runtime-in-Vis)

Por otro lado no evaluaste usar de origen de datos un `DataSet`, de esta forma no tendrias una conexion directa a la db, sino que cargas mediante codigo un Dataset tipado y lo asignas como Report Source, la conexion la controlas desde código y el reporte de abstrae de la db utilizada.

Entiendo que el ejemplo que has puesto quizas lo obtuviste de aqui

[How do i change logon info dynamically in crystal report and ms access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254335/how-do-i-change-logon-info-dynamically-in-crystal-report-and-ms-access)

Comment: El SetLogon con una base de datos de Microsoft Access no funciona. Por otro lado lo de hacerlo mediante DataSet es correcto, me funciona, pero lo que querría es que fuera el informe que abría la base de datos y no pasarle yo los resultados.

Comment: Entiendo, la verdad es que hace tiempo que no uso Crystal, pero cuando lo hice tuve tantos problemas con las conexiones a la db que decidi nunca mas conectarlo directo, es por eso que sugiero que si quieres evitarte probemas no lo conectes directo sino que uses dataset como origen de datos del reporte