# Como abrir mas de 2 bases de datos simultaneamente en access protegidas con contraseña en Crystal Report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Quisiera saber cómo puedo abrir simultáneamente 3 o 4 bases de datos Access protegidas con contraseña en Crystal Report.

Anteriormente leí el tema "[No puedo abrir un informe de crystal con una base de datos en Microsoft Access con contraseña](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4946/no-puedo-abrir-un-informe-de-crystal-con-una-base-de-datos-en-microsoft-access-c)". Agregué el código para esa respuesta y me funciona perfecto cuando es solo una base de datos.

Cuando es más de una base de datos, no funciona, solo reconoce las tablas de la última base de datos que leyó; y me envió un aviso que no localiza las tablas que se encuentran dentro de las otras bases de datos.

```
    Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
    Dim crtableLogoninfos As New TableLogOnInfos()
    Dim crtableLogoninfo As New TableLogOnInfo()
    Dim crConnectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo()
    Dim CrTables As Tables
    Dim CrTable As Table

    Dim crtableLogoninfos1 As New TableLogOnInfos()
    Dim crtableLogoninfo1 As New TableLogOnInfo()
    Dim crConnectionInfo1 As New ConnectionInfo()
    Dim CrTables1 As Tables
    Dim CrTable1 As Table


    cryRpt.Load("C:\Repor\Nota2.rpt")

    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    With crConnectionInfo
        .ServerName = ""
        .DatabaseName = "C:\BASES DE DATOS\FACTNH.mdb"
        .UserID = ""
        .Password = pwxmen
    End With

    CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables
    'For Each CrTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table In CrTables
    For Each CrTable In CrTables
        crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo
        crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo
        CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo)
    Next


    With crConnectionInfo1
        .ServerName = ""
        .DatabaseName = "C:\BASES DE DATOS\REGISTRO.mdb"
        .UserID = ""
        .Password = pwxmen
    End With

    CrTables1 = cryRpt.Database.Tables
    'For Each CrTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table In CrTables
    For Each CrTable1 In CrTables1
        crtableLogoninfo1 = CrTable1.LogOnInfo
        crtableLogoninfo1.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo1
        CrTable1.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo1)
    Next
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Reportes.CR1.ReportSource = cryRpt
    Reportes.CR1.Refresh()
    Reportes.CR1.Zoom(75)
    Reportes.Show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Realmente es algo sencillo evitando tener contraseña en la base de datos.

Creamos una base de datos Auxiliar.mdb que no contenga contraseña.
Creamos tablas que utilizamos en las otras bases de datos.
Limpio las tablas si contienen información.
Agrego la información unicamente de lo que necesito mostrar en el reporte dentro de las tablas.
Leemos directamente el reporte de esta base de datos que no contiene contraseña.
Termino de leer el reporte y elimino la información.

Sencillo sin complicaciones

Saludos